# Migrating custom database pages to Wordpress

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I've been toying with the idea of using Wordpress as a CMS to replace the various database-driven pages I've kludged together over the years. I'm wondering though if there's a seamless way to grab info from a database based on the URL.

e.g. I have pages that serve up info on awards

```
/academy-awards grabs the intro info from the database
/academy-awards/32 grabs the intro info about the 32nd edition
/academy-awards/32/winners grabs the results and commentary for that ceremony
```

Now, academy-awards is actually an extensionless php file and depending on what comes after it (nothing, a number, a number and word) it serves up the various pages.

How would/could I translate that work into Wordpress? I'm a complete WP noob, so I'm hoping your initial answers can help me dig a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around some more it appears I can access info from other databases by using Custom Queries (http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries) and combining them with page templates.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is already an import filter or plugin, there's no easy way to import post/page data into Wordpress posts/pages without making and using a custom database query that will insert what you want into the correct spots in the WP database schema.

That said, you can export tables out of phpmyadmin into CSV or plain text and then manipulate that data into a a file that when imported will generate WordPress posts/pages. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

Also think about setting set up a demo WordPress site, enter some posts/pages and then Export from Dashboard>>Tools>Export and see how a WordPress WXR file is constructed. That is a good format to arrange your data for import. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen

If you simply want to *display* data from another database, use the `wpdb Class`. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: I guess I was looking if there was a way to use path info to interact with custom php in a WP page. In the example above we use an nginx rewrite to turn the stuff after the /academy-awards into a custom GET variable that interacts with the PHP. Guess I'll have to see if I can pass variables through to WP.

Comment: Looks like there are ways to pass GET variables...I'll need to read up on that.

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted to import the data. Do you want to preserve/migrate the URL structure in Wordpress?

Comment: Yes. I've just found a few pages referencing using the query_vars hook i.e. you can tell WP that everything after /academy-awards should be passed to a variable.